# How can I convert the df column [JSON_Format] into multiple columns in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have got the data on JSON format from Kafka and read the data as a DataFrame in PySpark.

After I got the data from Kafka, it appeared as a DataFrame Format:

```
DataFrame[value: string]
```

However, the value is containing the JSON / DICT format.

Print Statment and return:

```
def print_row(row):
    print(row)
    pass

testing.writeStream.foreach(print_row).start()
```

```
Row(value='{col_1 =80.0, timestamp=2020-01-13T08:58:58.164Z}')
```

How can I convert from the value(JSON) into the DATAFRAME columns like:

```
col_1  timestamp
80.0   2020-01-13T08:58:58.164Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a schema and parse the JSON.

Copied from https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/26/processing-data-in-apache-kafka-with-structured-streaming-in-apache-spark-2-2.html

```
# value schema: { "a": 1, "b": "string" }
schema = StructType().add("a", IntegerType()).add("b", StringType())
df.select( \
  col("key").cast("string"),
  from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema))
```

Answer (score -1):

A DataFrame can be created for a JSON dataset represented by an RDD[String] storing one JSON object per string.

```
jsonStrings = ['{"name":"Yin","address":{"city":"Columbus","state":"Ohio"}}']
otherPeopleRDD = sc.parallelize(jsonStrings)
otherPeople = spark.read.json(otherPeopleRDD)
otherPeople.show()
```

Comment: since I have read the data from Kafka by following the below link. It returned the DataFrame Format rather than the JSON string. [link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)